# Error Loading Pipeline Assembly GifAnimation.dll

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, xna

When using the GifAnimation XNA package found here--http://xnagif.codeplex.com/

I get an error stating:

> Error 2   Error loading pipeline assembly "D:###\Documents##################\GifAnimation.Pipeline\bin\x86\Debug\GifAnimation.dll".

and the code breaks on this line:

```
animation = Content.Load<GifAnimation.GifAnimation>("Falling Stars");
```

I've checked the references of the project and they are all working, and the .dll file exists in the location the error is mentioning.

How do I fix this?
Thanks!